# No such file or directory -- Hadoop or HDFS error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to copy a file from my local file system to HDFS, but it is giving an error message.

The command is:

`hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /Users/admin/a.txt username98642`

And the error is:

> copyFromLocal: `/Users/admin/a.txt': No such file or directory

I have the file `a.txt` present on the local file system.

I have tried the permutations and combinations of the command.
Also I have the folder created on the server as well. But it is still showing this error. What could be wrong with this as the tutorial that I am following has this working.

OUTPUTS

FIRST TERMINAL:

> admins-Mac-mini:~ admin$ ls -la u.txt
>
> -rwxrwxrwx  1 admin  staff  4 Apr 17 16:13 u.txt

ON OTHER TERMINAL

> hirwuser150430@ip-171-30-45-205:~$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /Users/admin/u.txt sample
>
> copyFromLocal: `/Users/admin/u.txt': No such file or directory
>   hirwuser150430@ip-171-30-45-205:~$

Comment: Please check the directory and file permission on the local file.

Comment: Also please check if you are giving target hadoop path correctly

Comment: hi, I have changed the permissions ..still did not work. Also the "hadoop fs -ls " command is working. This hadoop is running on AWS. I have logged in using the username and password. Is this sufficient for it to work ? What do you mean by the target hadoop path info ?

Comment: hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /path/to/local/file  /path/to/target/hadoop/directory

Comment: This is how it should be given. Also m not sure what you are referring here as "username98642". Hope this helps.

Comment: That is the name of the directory on the hadoop that I have created using hadoop fs -mkdir <name>  command

Comment: @piyushpankaj see the edit. Nothing great .. but this is only what I have got.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141890/discussion-between-learnerios-and-piyush-pankaj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file (u.txt) must be present in (or reachable from) the same filesystem as the one you are running the `copyFromLocal` command (the one at ip-171-30-45-205). Copy the file to the remote computer using `scp` and then upload it to HDFS.

Check if the file is in the path you think it is, by using ls on the machine at ip-171-30-45-205.

```
ls /Users/admin/u.txt
```

It seems that on the other terminal your user name is hirwuser150430 and not admin...

Comment: The outputs shown is from the same computer(my local computer). I had opened 2 terminals for it. I connected to the Hadoop running on the ip 171-30-45-205 using username and password. The file is on my local system. I thought would copy it to the hadoop. The file is not present on 171-30-45-205. The ls command returned 'No such file' message.